# C++ initialize array with another array and new values

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, concatenation

I'm coming to C++ from python and would like to do the equivalent of this with arrays if possible:

```
both = [...]
a = [a1, a2] + both
[a1, a2, ...]
b = [b1, b2] + both
[b1, b2, ...]
```

Comment: You'll need to write code to do that; what have you written so far?

Comment: you should take a look at std::vector

Comment: Note: Arrays in C++ are derived from arrays in C, and arrays in C were designed to solve the problems of the time. That time was the 1970s. You'll find arrays in C++ to be incredibly simple and stupid. Prefer to use [a library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do such a thing with arrays you might consider the following code

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main()
    {
        int both[] ={1, 2, 3};
        std::cout << sizeof(both)/sizeof(*both);
        int a[sizeof(both)/sizeof(*both) + 2] = {4, 4};
        int b[sizeof(both)/sizeof(*both) + 2] = {5, 5};
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(both)/sizeof(*both); ++i)
        {
            a[2+i] = both[i];
            b[2+i] = both[i];
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

But since you are using c++, not c, you might really consider using one of the containers offered by c++ standard library

Comment: @Alexander Wilkinson Please, mark the answer that helped you to solve/solved your problem as a solution

Comment: Thank you! I know I could do this with vectors, I just would much prefer working with arrays as I really dislike the syntax for vectors. Silly reasoning, I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> both = {...};

std::vector<int> a = {a1, a2};
a.insert(a.end(), both.begin(), both.end());

std::vector<int> b = {b1, b2};
b.insert(b.end(), both.begin(), both.end());
```